# Make on Ubuntu a python executable that runs on Mac

Tags: cross-platform, executable

Is there a way to create a python executable on *Ubuntu* that can also run on *Mac*?

*Note:*
This executable doesn't have to run on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't!. Please refer to the following link:

https://dzone.com/articles/making-a-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-scri

There it state:

> The format/extension of the executable will depend on which operating
>   system you used for compilation. For example, if you run the
>   PyInstaller command on Windows the executable file will be .exe. If
>   you run it on Linux the extension will depend on the distribution you
>   are using.

A workaround to solve it is:

1. Run the OS virtually and, create executable in that virtual os and export it later.
2. `WINE` works as well! (Though, I didn’t try it myself), refer to the following link https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/12/27/how-to-cross-compile-a-python-script-into-a-windows-executable-on-linux/

Comment: If I understand correctly, without a virtual machine, there is a way to create a windows executable on Linux but there is not for Mac executables?

Comment: @Phineas Exactly, this is annoying. I guess a tool that can do it cross-platform could be extremely useful.